# itarate each property inside an array after a map fucntion and then return new array

Tags: arrays, typescript, object

`data.risk.scatterIndices.investments.map((el: any) => el.name) || []`

I have this map function that return an array like that

["pension","realestate","debt","kupot"]

expected output is ["פנסיה","נדלן,""הלוואות,""קופות"]

i want to translate each property of the array and return new array, how could i done it right?

Comment: What is the expected output? What is the input? What have you tried so far to solve this on your own ([mcve])?

Comment: Call map again passing in function that does translation of one element.

Comment: expected output is ["פנסיה","נדלן,""הלוואות,""קופות"]

Answer (score 0):

```
const investments = data.risk.scatterIndices.investments || [];
const translatedName = this.getTranslatedNames(investments);

private getTranslatedNames(investments: any[]){
    const names = investments.map((inv: any) => inv.name);
    const translatedNames = names.map(name => this.translate(name));
    return translatedNames;
}

private translate(name: string) {
    const translated = ...; // Your code for translation
    return translated;
}
```